# Deploying a Vue.js app on DigitalOcean

Tags: php, npm, vue.js, lamp, digital-ocean

I made an app using Vue.js on the frontend and Slim PHP on the backend and I want to deploy it on a DigitalOcean droplet.
So far, I've managed to do the following:

- Created a Ubuntu 16.06 droplet
- Updated it
- Installed Apache
- Installed MySQL + phpmyadmin
- Installed PHP
- Edited dir.conf (I put index.php on front of the list)
- Restarted Apache
- Prepared the Vue app with npm run build
- Copied the index.html and the /dist folder to /var/www/html/myapp

When I try to open myserverip/myapp in a browser, it just loads an blank html document. I noticed that the title is correct, but the #app div containing the application doesn't render.
What am I doing wrong? Do I need to spin up a node.js server, install another service or something else?

Comment: Can you please check your browser's console for any errors and report back?

Comment: Are you sure there's no other file dependencies besides the index file and dist/ folder? Could Vue be missing some component files, etc.?